# If A is an idempotent matrix then its eigenvalue is either 0 or 1. Is the converse true?

Tags: linear-algebra

If A is an idempotent matrix then its eigenvalue is either 0 or 1. Is the converse true? 
My intuition tell me that it is an if and only if statements because:

if $D=D^2$ then $P^{-1}AP=(P^{-1}AP)^2= P^{-1}A^2P$.

However, when I look at wikipedia and the linear model textbook I am using it seem like an implied statement not an if and only if statement. So I was wondering if I am missing something?

Comment: It's true for **diagonalisable** matrices, by your argument. It's not true in general, e.g. $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField The eigenvalues are $1$'s

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you. It seem like that was the gap in the explanation.